# How to WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml configuration in Spring JUnit Tests correct

Tags: java, spring, testing, maven

I have a maven based Spring 3.0 project. The Spring configuration file for the web application is located at `/<proj>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml`.

Now I want to have a JUnit test that checks if the context can be started. But I did not knwo how to specify the location of that file in the `@ContextConfiguration` tag in a maven correct way.

I am doing:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional()
@ContextConfiguration({
    "classpath:META-INF/spring/application-context.xml",
    "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml",
})
public class SpringMvcContextTest {
```

But I am pretty sure that I should not refer to the maven `src` directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on `maven` why don't you choose `resource` directory for this, and use `classpah:file.xml`