# In Junit test class I am not able read web-inf/*.xml through @ContextConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to create `ldaptemplate` instance in my Junit test class.
`spring-ldap.xml` is put at location

`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-ldap.xml` and my Junit test class are in different packages. 
I have tried all possible things with `@ContextConfiguration` e.g. below

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-ldap.xml" )
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:spring-ldap.xml" )
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-ldap.xml" )
```

When I run Junit test class it gives me error

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring-ldap.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Comment: 1)  You should really remove your personal contact information from here. 2)  It would help tons if you provided the test class you were talking about; from what it sounds like, the file path simply doesn't exist.  But we also don't fully understand how you're invoking the test.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8803149/how-to-web-inf-spring-webmvc-config-xml-configuration-in-spring-junit-tests-corr

Comment: Thanks Makoto for kind reply. Should I give complete code for mt test class? In development phase,  I am running the test class from eclispe Junit, by right click--> run as--> Junit test